# Differentiating new (wife and children) and old family (parents) in a dedication

Tags: meaning, british-english

I am writing a dedication:

> To my family, parents and mentors

**Parents were also my family when I was a kid. Thus, may this "overlap" in the differents terms cause confusion?**

A wordier option:

> To my wife, children, parents and mentors

Less wordier option:

> To my family and mentors

**Or how to solve this?**

Comment: Your parents are still part of your family, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go for "***To my wife, children, parents and mentors***". You honour them by naming every one of them, I wouldn't worry about wordiness. One consideration to take into account is:

> Think not just about the person or people named in the book dedication, but also about all of the readers who will pass by this page and be impacted. Make a conscious choice about what you want that impact to be (if any). ([Medium.com](https://medium.com/@tuckermax/how-to-write-your-book-dedication-without-getting-stuck-51f048b6681d))

As for the technical term, some use ***immediate family***, which

> normally includes a person's ***parents, siblings, spouses, children***, or an individual related by blood whose close association is an equivalent of a family relationship. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_family))

In law they also use the phrase ***close family member*** which includes:

> the individual's spouse; the individual's and the spouse's
> grandparents, parents, siblings, children, nieces, nephews, aunts,
> uncles and first cousins; the spouse of any of these people; and any
> other individuals who share the same household with the Government
> Official. ([Lawinsider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/close-family-member#:%7E:text=Close%20Family%20Member%20means%20the%20individual%27s%20spouse%3B%20the%20individual%27s%20and,household%20with%20the%20Government%20Official.)) - includes too many.

There doesn't seem to exist a name which would include only your wife and children (and parents).

Answer (score 0):

You could say generations.

"To generations of my family and mentors..."
or,
"To generations of 'Smiths', mentors, honored guests..."

I think it would border on insulting to split hairs and say,
"To my immediate family, my parents, my mentors..."